# Spark ar, how to create shoot effect

Tags: apache-spark, augmented-reality

I am trying to develop simple game, where I need to shoot bullets. Bullet motion must occur relative to world space. But direction of flight is set normally to smartphone at the moment of shooting. 
 The problem is to calculate destination point. I thought of the following steps:
subscribe to trigger event and do in script
DeviceMotion.worldTransform
Applied to vector(0,0,1) (it is normal direction to camera)
to get the end point in world coordnate stystem.
Then I use script output in patch editor to set end point in transition block of my 3d-object to animate shooting.
I am new to reactive programming, so I'm not sure this concept is correct.
So is it right algorithm? Can anybody give me tips how should I calculate the destination point?

Comment: From Review: Would you mind sharing the relevant part of your [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode)? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it... you could get your endpoint using the point-tracking/point-anchor, then animate the transition between the camera transform and the tracker transform, using Reactive.mix

```
//get start and end transforms
let start = Camera.worldTransform;
let end = tracker.globalTransform;

//setup animation
let driver = Animation.timeDriver({durationMilliseconds: 100});
let sampler = Animation.samplers.linear(0,1);
let anim = Animation.animation(driver, sampler);

//setup bullet transforms
bullet.x = Reactive.mix(start.x, end.x, anim);
bullet.y = Reactive.mix(start.y, end.y, anim);
bullet.z = Reactive.mix(start.z, end.z, anim);

//start the animation
driver.start();
```

Good luck!